# laravel validator should't required when we define specific id

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

in this laravel validator class i want to choose specify `id` for `required`, when we define specify is for example `parent` shouldn't required or `status` and i don't know how can i make this validation

for example:

```
'parent'=>'required/*when id is not 1*/|integer',
'status'=>'required/*when id is not 1*/|string',

class RequestCategory extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'category_name'=>'required|string|min:5:max:20',
            'parent'=>'required|integer',
            'status'=>'required|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if)  validation in order to achieve this. Sintax goes like this:

```
'field_name' => 'required_if:columnName:value'
```

I think you could try this:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'category_name'=>'required|string|min:5:max:20',
            'parent'=>'required_if:status,!=,1|integer',
            'status'=>'required_if:parent,!=,1|string',
        ];
    }
```

PS: Not tested, if there are any errors here, let me know.